# on click function to add a class is not working in ie9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, debugging, onclick

http://koovay.com/test/rodriguez/

I have a few various on click functions set that do not seem to work in IE9.

I have a few .components in my mark-up, heres one:

```
<div class="tour-tab component">
<a href="#" id="tour-component"><i class="icon-earth"></i><span> Tour    Dates</span></a>
<div id="event-content" class="component-content">
<div class="attached-art"><span></span></div>
<h2>Upcoming Shows</h2>
  <ul>
  <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'home_tour' ); ?>
  <h4><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>tour-dates">See  All</a></h4>
  </ul>
</div> <!-- end content -->
```

```
$('.component').on('tap', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.component.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

I'm simply trying to add a class to the component, which in turn will add a "display:block" to the .component-content

I'm using tappy.js which is why is says 'tap' instead of 'click', but it did not work either way...

Answer (score 0):

The tappy docs use .bind and not .on. Have you tried using .bind('tap',...) rather than .on('tap', ...)? That may do the trick.

Comment: I did, thanks! I actually just changed it due to an issue on their github page, it suggested using .on instead of .bind for a slight perf gain.

Comment: I actually just found .enquire.js to be the culprit, I had no polyfil set up for it. When I removed it, all is working.

Answer (score 0):

Error from enquire.js was causing the on.click issues.